# EOFException while reading InflaterInputStream from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, servlets

I have an API to which client can make request by sending the compressed request. Compression is done using the Deflator following way.

Request payload:

```
public byte[] compressRequest(String requestString) {
    int reqLength = requestString.length();
    int temp = (int)(1.001D * (double)reqLength + 1.0D) + 12;
    byte[] byteArr = requestString.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(temp);
    DeflaterOutputStream deflaterOutputStream = new DeflaterOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
    deflaterOutputStream.write(byteArr);
    deflaterOutputStream.close();
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

At the server side, I am trying to extract and decompress the data following way.

The same code is working fine on Java7 and Servlet based application. But in java 8 and Spring boot based application I am getting following exception `java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream` at line `inputLine = in.readLine())`

```
@PostMapping(value = "saverecord")
public void hello(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType("application/binary");
    InflaterInputStream is = InflaterInputStream(request.getInputStream());
    String requestXMLStr = extract(is, 0);
    ServletOutputStream out = response
                .getOutputStream();

    // some processing and return response
}

private String extract(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(inputLine);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I tried following two things suggested in other SO answers, but neither worked.

```
InflaterInputStream is = InflaterInputStream(request.getInputStream(), new Inflater(false)); // tried true also
```

tried setting up encoding

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "US-ASCII"));
```

PS: For some project specific reasons I cannot use `@RequestBody` in the project.

Comment: Shouldn't the gzip be handled by the servlet container? Or shouldn't you be handling this in a `Filter` wrapping the request/response to handle this transparantly? That way you can use all the other Spring features again. ALso instead of your `extract` method and reading lines you might want to use the `StreamUtils.copyToString` method (which reads in a different way).

Comment: @M.Deinum Due to legacy reasons I cannot make significant changes in the code.

Comment: Compressed data is not text-only and should not be processed with a `Reader`. Use an input stream.

Comment: Why don't you use Java [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html)? [Example](https://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-string#converting-with-javanio). And why it's `US-ASCII` charset and not `UTF-8`?